# How do I execute a shell builtin after executing a shell automatically without using profile and RC files?

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to execute my shell with the environment I provide as the command line arguments. For that I have a script that ends with `exec zsh -d -f` after setting all the variables I want, which gives me a new shell with all variables set.

e.g:

```
export MY_SESSION="$1"
cd $2
export PS1="$3; "
exec zsh -d -f
```

My issue is that, I also want to execute `bindkey -e` on the new shell before it is made available. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with `expect`. Here is what I did.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect


spawn /bin/zsh -d -f
send "source ./bin/activate\r"
send "export PS1='*| '\r"
send "bindkey -e\r"
interact
```

This successfully sends the `bindkey -e` on the produced zsh shell.